# Is there any way to add action listener after everything is created?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, windowbuilder

I have been learning to program java from a while. I heard if I have any problems with my code I can ask here, so I do it now I guess. I am now learning to use windowbuilder addon in eclipse. I heard that adding action listener would solve my problem, but there is another problem. I don't know if it's possible to add action listener and connect everything with him after everything is designed. I want to listen to those fields because I need predefined variables for calculating.
I need to listen on getEggAmount,getMilkAmount and getFlourAmount JTextFields.
My mainmenu class is here:

```
public class main {

  private JFrame frmBlinmaker;
  private JTextField getMilkAmount;
  private JTextField getFlourAmount;
  private JLabel MilkAmount;
  private JLabel FlourAmount;
  private JLabel MakeableBlins;
  private JLabel setMakeableBlins;
  private JLabel EggPortions;
  private JLabel MilkPortions;
  private JLabel FlourPortions;
  private JLabel setEggPortions;
  private JLabel setMilkPortions;
  private JLabel setFlourPortions;
  private JLabel EggNeed;
  private JLabel setEggNeed;
  private JLabel MilkNeed;
  private JLabel setMilkNeed;
  private JLabel FlourNeed;
  private JLabel lblNewLabel;
  private JLabel eggs;
  private JLabel milliliter;
  private JLabel grams;
  private JTextField setEggAmount;
  public int setResults() {
    makeable k = new makeable();
    int getResults = k.setFinalResult();
    return getResults;
  }

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                main window = new main();
                window.frmBlinmaker.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public main() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frmBlinmaker = new JFrame();
    frmBlinmaker.setTitle("BlinMaker");
    frmBlinmaker.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frmBlinmaker.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    SpringLayout springLayout = new SpringLayout();
    frmBlinmaker.getContentPane().setLayout(springLayout);

    JButton Calculate = new JButton("CALCULATE");
    Calculate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            makeable k = new makeable();
            k.main();
            setMakeableBlins.setText(Integer.toString(setResults()));
        }
    });
    Calculate.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
    frmBlinmaker.getContentPane().add(Calculate);

    getMilkAmount = new JTextField();
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, Calculate, 0, SpringLayout.WEST, getMilkAmount);
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, Calculate, 0, SpringLayout.EAST, getMilkAmount);
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, getMilkAmount, 45, SpringLayout.NORTH, frmBlinmaker.getContentPane());
    getMilkAmount.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 10));
    getMilkAmount.setText("Type here in milliliter");
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, getMilkAmount, 10, SpringLayout.WEST, frmBlinmaker.getContentPane());
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, getMilkAmount, 122, SpringLayout.WEST, frmBlinmaker.getContentPane());
    frmBlinmaker.getContentPane().add(getMilkAmount);
    getMilkAmount.setColumns(10);

    getFlourAmount = new JTextField();
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, Calculate, 6, SpringLayout.SOUTH, getFlourAmount);
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, getFlourAmount, 80, SpringLayout.NORTH, frmBlinmaker.getContentPane());
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, getMilkAmount, -6, SpringLayout.NORTH, getFlourAmount);
    getFlourAmount.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 10));
    getFlourAmount.setText("Type here in grams");
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, getFlourAmount, -153, SpringLayout.SOUTH, frmBlinmaker.getContentPane());
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, getFlourAmount, 10, SpringLayout.WEST, frmBlinmaker.getContentPane());
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, getFlourAmount, 122, SpringLayout.WEST, frmBlinmaker.getContentPane());
    frmBlinmaker.getContentPane().add(getFlourAmount);
    getFlourAmount.setColumns(10);

    JButton getHelp = new JButton("What is this program?");
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, Calculate, -65, SpringLayout.NORTH, getHelp);
    getHelp.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 10));
    getHelp.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            mainhelp m = new mainhelp();
            m.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, getHelp, -46, SpringLayout.SOUTH, frmBlinmaker.getContentPane());
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, getHelp, 10, SpringLayout.WEST, frmBlinmaker.getContentPane());
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, getHelp, -10, SpringLayout.SOUTH, frmBlinmaker.getContentPane());
    frmBlinmaker.getContentPane().add(getHelp);

    JLabel EggAmount = new JLabel("Egg Amount");
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, EggAmount, 128, SpringLayout.WEST, frmBlinmaker.getContentPane());
    EggAmount.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11));
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, EggAmount, 17, SpringLayout.NORTH, frmBlinmaker.getContentPane());
    frmBlinmaker.getContentPane().add(EggAmount);

    MilkAmount = new JLabel("Milk Amount");
    MilkAmount.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11));
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, MilkAmount, 7, SpringLayout.NORTH, getMilkAmount);
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, MilkAmount, 6, SpringLayout.EAST, getMilkAmount);
    frmBlinmaker.getContentPane().add(MilkAmount);

    FlourAmount = new JLabel("Flour Amount");
    FlourAmount.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11));
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, FlourAmount, 7, SpringLayout.NORTH, getFlourAmount);
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, FlourAmount, 6, SpringLayout.EAST, getFlourAmount);
    frmBlinmaker.getContentPane().add(FlourAmount);

    MakeableBlins = new JLabel("The amount of makeable blins is:");
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, MakeableBlins, 10, SpringLayout.NORTH, frmBlinmaker.getContentPane());
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, MakeableBlins, 218, SpringLayout.WEST, frmBlinmaker.getContentPane());
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, EggAmount, -22, SpringLayout.WEST, MakeableBlins);
    MakeableBlins.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC, 11));
    frmBlinmaker.getContentPane().add(MakeableBlins);

    setMakeableBlins = new JLabel("0");
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, setMakeableBlins, 22, SpringLayout.SOUTH, MakeableBlins);
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, setMakeableBlins, 94, SpringLayout.EAST, FlourAmount);
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, setMakeableBlins, 105, SpringLayout.SOUTH, MakeableBlins);
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, setMakeableBlins, -90, SpringLayout.EAST, frmBlinmaker.getContentPane());
    setMakeableBlins.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 73));
    frmBlinmaker.getContentPane().add(setMakeableBlins);

    EggPortions = new JLabel("Portions of egg:");
    EggPortions.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
    frmBlinmaker.getContentPane().add(EggPortions);

    MilkPortions = new JLabel("Portions of milk:");
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, MilkPortions, 153, SpringLayout.WEST, frmBlinmaker.getContentPane());
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, getHelp, -6, SpringLayout.WEST, MilkPortions);
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, EggPortions, 0, SpringLayout.WEST, MilkPortions);
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, EggPortions, -6, SpringLayout.NORTH, MilkPortions);
    MilkPortions.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
    frmBlinmaker.getContentPane().add(MilkPortions);

    FlourPortions = new JLabel("Portions of flour:");
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, FlourPortions, 6, SpringLayout.EAST, getHelp);
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, FlourPortions, -10, SpringLayout.SOUTH, frmBlinmaker.getContentPane());
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, MilkPortions, -6, SpringLayout.NORTH, FlourPortions);
    FlourPortions.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
    frmBlinmaker.getContentPane().add(FlourPortions);

    setEggPortions = new JLabel("0");
    setEggPortions.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, setEggPortions, 1, SpringLayout.NORTH, EggPortions);
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, setEggPortions, 6, SpringLayout.EAST, EggPortions);
    frmBlinmaker.getContentPane().add(setEggPortions);

    setMilkPortions = new JLabel("0");
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, setMilkPortions, 5, SpringLayout.SOUTH, setEggPortions);
    setMilkPortions.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, setMilkPortions, 6, SpringLayout.EAST, MilkPortions);
    frmBlinmaker.getContentPane().add(setMilkPortions);

    setFlourPortions = new JLabel("0");
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, setFlourPortions, -10, SpringLayout.SOUTH, frmBlinmaker.getContentPane());
    setFlourPortions.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, setFlourPortions, 6, SpringLayout.EAST, FlourPortions);
    frmBlinmaker.getContentPane().add(setFlourPortions);

    EggNeed = new JLabel("You will need:");
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, EggNeed, 0, SpringLayout.NORTH, EggPortions);
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, EggNeed, 15, SpringLayout.EAST, setEggPortions);
    EggNeed.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
    frmBlinmaker.getContentPane().add(EggNeed);

    setEggNeed = new JLabel("0");
    setEggNeed.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, setEggNeed, 1, SpringLayout.NORTH, EggPortions);
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, setEggNeed, 6, SpringLayout.EAST, EggNeed);
    frmBlinmaker.getContentPane().add(setEggNeed);

    MilkNeed = new JLabel("You will need:");
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, MilkNeed, 6, SpringLayout.SOUTH, EggNeed);
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, MilkNeed, 0, SpringLayout.EAST, EggNeed);
    MilkNeed.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
    frmBlinmaker.getContentPane().add(MilkNeed);

    setMilkNeed = new JLabel("0");
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, setMilkNeed, 5, SpringLayout.SOUTH, setEggNeed);
    setMilkNeed.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, setMilkNeed, 0, SpringLayout.WEST, setEggNeed);
    frmBlinmaker.getContentPane().add(setMilkNeed);

    FlourNeed = new JLabel("You will need:");
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, FlourNeed, -10, SpringLayout.SOUTH, frmBlinmaker.getContentPane());
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, FlourNeed, 0, SpringLayout.EAST, EggNeed);
    FlourNeed.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
    frmBlinmaker.getContentPane().add(FlourNeed);

    lblNewLabel = new JLabel("0");
    lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, lblNewLabel, 0, SpringLayout.NORTH, FlourPortions);
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, lblNewLabel, 0, SpringLayout.WEST, setEggNeed);
    frmBlinmaker.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);

    eggs = new JLabel("eggs");
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, eggs, 0, SpringLayout.NORTH, EggPortions);
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, eggs, 6, SpringLayout.EAST, setEggNeed);
    eggs.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
    frmBlinmaker.getContentPane().add(eggs);

    milliliter = new JLabel("ml");
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, milliliter, 6, SpringLayout.SOUTH, eggs);
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, milliliter, 6, SpringLayout.EAST, setMilkNeed);
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, milliliter, -18, SpringLayout.EAST, frmBlinmaker.getContentPane());
    milliliter.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
    frmBlinmaker.getContentPane().add(milliliter);

    grams = new JLabel("grams");
    grams.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, grams, 0, SpringLayout.NORTH, FlourPortions);
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, grams, 6, SpringLayout.EAST, lblNewLabel);
    frmBlinmaker.getContentPane().add(grams);

    JButton getHelpForNeed = new JButton("What is this here?");
    getHelpForNeed.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 10));
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, getHelpForNeed, -32, SpringLayout.NORTH, EggNeed);
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, getHelpForNeed, 0, SpringLayout.WEST, EggNeed);
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, getHelpForNeed, -9, SpringLayout.NORTH, EggNeed);
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, getHelpForNeed, 0, SpringLayout.EAST, eggs);
    frmBlinmaker.getContentPane().add(getHelpForNeed);

    JButton getHelpForPortions = new JButton("What is this here?");
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, getHelpForPortions, 23, SpringLayout.NORTH, getHelpForNeed);
    getHelpForPortions.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 10));
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, getHelpForPortions, 0, SpringLayout.NORTH, getHelpForNeed);
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, getHelpForPortions, 0, SpringLayout.WEST, EggPortions);
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, getHelpForPortions, 0, SpringLayout.EAST, setFlourPortions);
    frmBlinmaker.getContentPane().add(getHelpForPortions);

    setEggAmount = new JTextField();
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, setEggAmount, -7, SpringLayout.NORTH, EggAmount);
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, setEggAmount, 10, SpringLayout.WEST, frmBlinmaker.getContentPane());
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, setEggAmount, -6, SpringLayout.NORTH, getMilkAmount);
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, setEggAmount, -6, SpringLayout.WEST, EggAmount);
    frmBlinmaker.getContentPane().add(setEggAmount);
    setEggAmount.setColumns(10);
}
public int getEggAmount() {
    int getEggAmount;
    getEggAmount = Integer.parseInt(setEggAmount.getText());
    return getEggAmount;
}
public int getMilkAmount() {
    int setMilkAmount;
    setMilkAmount = Integer.parseInt(getMilkAmount.getText());
    return setMilkAmount;
}
public int getFlourAmount() {
    int setFlourAmount;
    setFlourAmount = Integer.parseInt(getFlourAmount.getText());
    return setFlourAmount;
}
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible, and it's generally not the most tricky thing to achieve

Comment: I just want to ask if someone can link a video to me that is doing that or similar thing? I was trying to do this last night but I was unsuccessful in finding any handy videos.

Comment: *I am now learning to use windowbuilder addon in eclipse* - I wouldn't to that. Don't spend your time learning the IDE. Spend your time learning Java/Swing. Don't use the IDE to create your forms. Just use the IDE to help debug and organize the code. If you write you own code then you can do whatever you want and you are not restricted to how the IDE works. Adding an ActionListener to a button is a single statement: `button.addActionListener(…)`. If you don't know how to do this, then you are not learning Swing.